# Problem with start GDB (MinGW-w64) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, gcc, visual-studio-code, gdb, g++

The debugger in MS VSC  won't work: but there are no errors, no warning. After start Debugging (F5) shows that in the console:

```
Executing task: d:\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe -g D:\Temp\helloworld\helloworld.cpp -o D:\Temp\helloworld\helloworld.exe <    
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

debugger looks like invoked to start, but waits a couple of seconds it stops, without tracing inside or just direct execution without debugging. The executable is created without and errors an warning and works ok.

Everything was taken from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) (incl example).

The launch.json file is also simple:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "D:\\Temp\\helloworld\\helloworld.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true },
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "D:\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are no spaces in directory names or other known issues,
as diagnosed with MinGW by others.  The firewall and AV are terminated.
Several times tried to reinstall MS VSC and MinGW, but it ain't help.

Comment: Did you have some breakpoints set?

Comment: Yes, I have on main enter.